# Restriction to a line is an immersion.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I have proved that $g: \mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow S^1, g(t) = (\cos 2 \pi t, \sin 2 \pi t)$, is a local diffeomorphism, as well as that

> $G: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1, G = g \times g$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Now the question is

> If $L$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the restriction $G: L \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ is an immersion.

Since restricted to $L$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^1$, So I would like to use the conclusion [Restriction of an immersion to any submanifold is still an immersion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434583/restriction-to-any-submanifold-of-its-domain-is-still-immersion) Is that all? Regardless, the aforementioned problem is not well justified. It would be great if someone could help me check it out.

Thanks.